# Is Buddha the root of Dhamma?

Tags: dhammas, chinese-canon

[Here](https://suttacentral.net/sa80/en/analayo) Monks praise Buddha by exclaiming the following:

> The monks said to the Buddha: “The Buddha is the root of the Dharma,
>   the eye of Dharma, the foundation of the Dharma. May he teach us!
>   Having heard him teach the Dharma, the monks will receive it
>   respectfully as he has taught it.”

My questions are :

What is the meaning of the fact that Buddha is the root of Dhamma? 
Similarly what is the meaning of the fact that Buddha is the eye of Dhamma? And what is the meaning of the fact that Buddha is the foundation of Dhamma ?

Comment: Where did you find these? Please quote sources.

Comment: @ruben2020 I have updated the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- Buddha is the root of the Dhamma as in Buddha is the root source of his teaching.
- Buddha is the eye of the Dhamma as in the Buddha's omniscience and all seeing knowledges are what see the the Dhamma that is hidden from the world.
- Buddha is the foundation of the Dhamma as in the Dhamma preached by his followers are based on the teachings of the Buddha.